# Pretest Posttest with 2 groups

Tags: anova, pre-post-comparison

Help!  I have 2 groups (New Professionals and Experienced Professionals) would have received the same training.  Both groups were given a survey before and after the training.  I have not been given the survey, but I do have 18 variables provided in the data set as clues to what was is the survey.  I am suppose to report on the usefulness of the survey and draw conclusions for future trainings.  There are 59 total participants.  There are 35 new professionals and 24 experienced professionals.

Should I use a principal component factor analysis, then chi square to test the differences between groups or run MANOVA with the pretest as a covariate? Will the different number of professionals in the groups hurt my analysis?

Comment: Hi Renee and welcome. Please have a look through the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), especially the early sections on how to ask questions. CrossValidated relies on a question-and-answer format, but this question doesn't appear to contain any actual questions. Please try to formulate specific questions and edit your question accordingly so that we can understand how to help.

Comment: Should I use a principal component factor analysis, then chi square to test the differences between groups or run MANOVA with the pretest as a covariate?  Will the different number of professionals in the groups hurt my analysis?

Comment: Hi again Renee. This is a definite improvement, but it needs to go in your question. I'll edit it in for you.